# Why some compounds form different crystal structure at different temperature?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

Lets take an example :-

> Sodium superoxide has three different crystal structure, the marcasite
>   structure at nearby 81 K, the pyrite structure between 196 K and 223 K
>   and calcium carbide structure at room temperature.

There are many more compounds which have different structure at different temperature. If temperature is increased, bonds breaks, atoms scatters and decomposes into a different **product (compound or element)** . But this does not happen. Rather bond breaks, atoms rearranges to form a different structure of same compound.  Why does this happen?

Comment: You may just as well think it all did happen: bonds broke, atoms scattered, etc. After all, same compound with different structure is but a particular case of "different product".

Comment: Why do things melt or boil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just entering into the field of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(materials_science)). I couldnt find any source for **Why** polymorphism occurs but you can think about it as *Energetically favorable* structure at a particular temperature.

Related - [Why polymorphs form?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/6616/11310)